# c# booleans: return true if first boolean is true and the second is false

Tags: c#, if-statement, boolean

I'm learning C# and have attempted this question. Please see my two attempts underneath the question below, and can someone point out to me where/how I have gone wrong please? Thanks.

**Attempt 1:**
        **Return true if the first boolean is true and the second is false.**

```
public static bool ReturnTrueAndFalse(bool boolean1, bool boolean2)
{
    if (boolean1 = true && (boolean2 = false))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
public static bool ReturnTrueAndFalse(bool boolean1, bool boolean2)
{
    boolean1 = true;
    boolean2 = false;
    return boolean1 && boolean2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your attempt below. On checking if boolean1 is true, you are saying 'boolean1 set to true' you arent checking if it is true, the same for boolean2.

```
public static bool ReturnTrueAndFalse(bool boolean1, bool boolean2)
{
    if (boolean1 = true && (boolean2 = false))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have fixed your code and this will work.

```
public static bool ReturnTrueAndFalse(bool boolean1, bool boolean2)
{
    if (boolean1 == true && boolean2 == false)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In your if conditions you need to add '==' instead of just '=', to check if it does equal the value you are checking against.

Comment: Thanks. They both worked great. The second code you gave (the one I tried) is more naturally how I think. Even though the first code is more efficient, so to speak, I need to get my head around it. The part that says "return boolean 1" - does this imply that when you write that, you are automatically telling the computer the boolean1 is true? Is that how it works?

Comment: When you are learning C# I personally found it was best to learn the long way of doing things first, to get your head round it; and then to bring in efficiency.

    public static bool ReturnTrueAndFalse(bool boolean1, bool boolean2)
    {
        return boolean1 && !boolean2;
    }

What this is doing is, it's saying 'return boolean1' but what we cant see is 'return boolean1 if true' so its doing a inline check if its true. We are then adding the other condition and returning boolean2 if it is not true, hence '!boolean2'. This is what the '!' is doing, "if not true (var)' = !boolean2

Answer (score 6):

a single `=` sets a variable.
You need to use a double.

Also, you can rewrite it somewhat.

```
public static bool ReturnTrueAndFalse(bool boolean1, bool boolean2)
{
    return boolean1 && !boolean2;
}
```

if you want to keep it as you have it, it would be like this:

```
public static bool ReturnTrueAndFalse(bool boolean1, bool boolean2)
{
    if (boolean1 == true && boolean2 == false)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. They both worked great. The second code you gave (the one I tried) is more naturally how I think. Even though the first code is more efficient, so to speak, I need to get my head around it. The part that says "return boolean 1" - does this imply that when you write that, you are automatically telling the computer the boolean1 is true? Is that how it works?

Comment: the return statement is going to be `true` or `false`. If you say `return boolean1` and boolean1 is `true`, return will be true. So combines it is `return true && not false`